# Does import statement need semicolon actually?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I found some import statements of my .ts files in ionic projects are written as:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
```

instead of

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

,which misses a semicolon, and the projects seems run normally, is the import statement need a semicolon at the end actually?

Comment: Semicolons are optional in js.

Comment: @LyubimovRoman Except when they're not.

Comment: @torazaburo so when are they not? They are necessary only for minification.

Comment: @LyubimovRoman The classic example is `foo(x) [newline] (y)`, which without a semicolon would be interpreted as `foo(x)(y)`.

Comment: @LyubimovRoman Or `foo(x) [newline] [1].concat([2])`- or any line starting with a square bracket really. They are definitely not only necessary for minification.

Comment: Semicolons are not optional in JS but the language has feature called Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI) which *literally* detects invalid code and tries to fix it by inserting a semicolon. Writing your own code without semicolons is same as writing English with incorrect grammar in MS Word and trusting the text assist to output correct grammar. For details, see https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-7.9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript only requires semicolons to separate statements in the same line. However I'd recommend you to stick to the good practices and use them.

From the [style guide for typescript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/styleguide/styleguide.html#semicolons)

> Use semicolons:

**Reasons:** 
Explicit semicolons helps language formatting tools give consistent results. Missing ASI (automatic semicolon insertion) can trip new devs e.g.

```
foo() (function(){})
```

will be a single statement (not two).

I understand that ultimately this is a matter of style, as you shouldn't have any issues if you don't use them when they are not strictly required, although in order to be consistent, it's better to use them than not.

This is a pretty good article also. https://www.codecademy.com/blog/78

Hope this helps!

Comment: *Javascript only requires semicolons to separate statements in the same line.* Strictly, speaking, this is not true. It also requires semi-colons to separate constructs which could be, but are not meant to be, interpreted as a single statement.

Comment: Javascript Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI) is literally automatic system to fix *invalid code*. If you leave semicolons off from your JavaScript, it's no different from writing things intentionally incorrectly in MS Word and trusting the automation to fix the grammar mistakes for you. For details, see https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-7.9

Answer (score 2):

OP is asking about if semicolons are required **in an import statement**.

Use semi colons when declaring variables, returning something or making variable calls, as you are declaring a variable with the import it is my understanding that you should use a semicolon.

Comment: Can you clarify what "making variable calls" are?

Comment: When you call/use a variable, like in the after statements section here: https://news.codecademy.com/your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript/